# Attempt to migrate on canary 5

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I've try to migrate to android-studio 3 canary 5 and got this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':data:createFullJarDebug'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/data_debug.kotlin_module
```

In project I have 3 module `app`, `data`, `domain` and I tried add

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/data_debug.kotlin_module'
}
```

to `app` and `data` but the error appears all over.

**other**

In `build.gradle` I added

```
javaCompileOptions {
    annotationProcessorOptions {
        includeCompileClasspath = true
    } 
}
```

changed `compile` to `implementation` and remove `retrolambda` that is all what I did for migrate to new Android Studio. Please help me fix this error.

**update**

canary 7 problem not disappear

Comment: Canary 5 is too buggy for me. So, my suggest is go back to canary 4.

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to have some properties defined on the class level, something like this

```
private const val PARAM_FIRST = "some_param"
private const val PARAM_SECOND = "second_param"

class CloudStore {
    // ...
}
```

If the answer is 'yes', try to move them into the companion object, like so:

```
class CloudStore {

    companion object {
        private const val PARAM_FIRST = "some_param"
        private const val PARAM_SECOND = "second_param"
    }

    // ...
}
```

I've had the similar issue which disappeared once I moved these parameters inside the class. I did not investigate the issue once if was resolved, so I can't say what was the exact cause: whether something is broken in AS 3.0, Gradle 4.1 or Kotlin 1.1.3-2 (they were all updated at once in my case).

Comment: I don't have kotlin files with constant, only with extention methods, if I'll have more time, I try replace them all to util methods.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Android Studio 3.0 stable. **Build** → **Clean Project** resolved this problem.